# Handling network disconnect while loading Google maps asynchronously

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Trying to load the Google maps asynchronously so that the start of the HTML page is faster.

Have used the following code as mentioned in the link: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#asynch. Section: Asynchronously Loading the API.

```js
function initialize() {
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
}

function loadScript() {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&sensor=TRUE_OR_FALSE&callback=initialize";
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

window.onload = loadScript;
```

**Issues:**

1. When the network is disconnected after the `loadScript()` function is invoked.  Currently we do not find anyway to check the network connection is terminated & do appropriate error handling.
2. Even when the network is available some times the callback function '`initialize()`' is never called.
3. Loading of google maps on mobile device is very slow even on a 3G network.

   In both the cases mentioned above, we start a loading icon immediately after `loadScript()` is invoked.  As `initialize()` is not called back it gets blocked in the loading icon for infinite time.

Kindly provide some pointers to handle the network disconnect & callback function not invoked issues.

Answer (score 1):

The Maps API does not have a native way to handle this. Thankfully HTML5 does. Listening to the document.online / document.offline events is very effective and I have used it to solve this problem.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document#Event_handlers

This is supported in at least iOS 5 and Android 2.3.

You could also use setTimeout to check that the API callback has occurred and handle it appropriately if not.